# Shatter a object then transform pieces to new object

Tags: animation, objects, transforms

I’m currently working on an animation project and I’ve been asked to make a solid block fall from the sky, hit the ground, shatter and then have those pieces come together to form a logo.

I’ve tried googling this but I haven’t found any videos that really touch on this (probably not wording it correctly). Does anyone have any information as to how this could work? I know I could have the block transform into the logo but I’m wanting to shatter those pieces and then get those pieces to come together to form this logo. Keep in mind I already have modeled out the logo and already have each piece as an object inside blender.

Thanks for any help!